# Update or remove value Vertica

Tags: vertica

I have next sql structure table:

```
id |  account_id  | app_id |  setting  |  value
```

example data:

```
  1 | 8fb38bac-6896-49e8-ac92-4cf6300ccd6f | 1      | recipients | taras@gmail.com
  2 | 8fb38bac-6896-49e8-ac92-4cf6300ccd6f | 1      | day        | monday
  3 | 8fb38bac-6896-49e8-ac92-4cf6300ccd6f | 1      | count      | 1234
```

And need update this data if I send new value or remove if don't exist in request to db.

If I sending (**recipients, day, count**) with new value update existing data, but if I send just (**recipients, day**) to update this data and remove **count**.

I try use next code:

```
 update settings 
set setting='count', value='1' 
where account_id='8fb38bac-6896-49e8-ac92-4cf6300ccd6f' and app_id='1';
```

But this script update all field in table.
How to fix it?

Comment: What database provider?

Comment: update settings 
set  value='1' 
where account_id='8fb38bac-6896-49e8-ac92-4cf6300ccd6f' and app_id='1' and setting='count';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the input , it looks like lots of values in the table have same value for `account_id` and `app_id` , hence when you are running your script, it is updating all the values.

If you only want to update rows with `count` in settings, do -

```
update settings 
set value='1' 
where account_id='8fb38bac-6896-49e8-ac92-4cf6300ccd6f' and app_id='1' and setting='count' and (value is not null and value <> '');
```

To remove the row

```
delete from settings
account_id='8fb38bac-6896-49e8-ac92-4cf6300ccd6f' and app_id='1' and setting='count' and (value is null or value = '');
```

Comment: ok, thanks, but how to remove some data if him value in query to db is empty?

Comment: remove the row completely?

Comment: Yes, value is null - remove the row completely

Comment: Please raise the issue of the cost associated with performing an `UPDATE` or `DELETE` in Vertica.